# Touchscreen partially not working, digitizer broken? (image included)

Tags: touchscreen, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-v

I have an Xperia V and two rows on the touchscreen are not responding. I dropped my phone but there's no scratches on it, so I don't know if its software issue or hardware as I noticed this problems hours after the incident. I Guess it's the digitizer. I opened it but everything seemed intact. Anyone had the same issue? How can I repair it or the display should be replaced?
Many thanks in advance.
P.S. I´ve factory reset my phone but the problem remains. Some repair shops told me to replace the whole display but I´m not sure if that´s necessary.  
Here's the touchscreen test image, almost half of the screen not responding to touches(although works with a mouse attached to phone via OTG cabel):

[image: ente image description here]

Comment: I guess it's not much use if you get a bunch of "me too". So maybe you [edit] your question to include which direction you want to go: Repair? Work-around the "blind area"? In the latter case: which part is affected (soft buttons maybe)?

Comment: I don't think we can really help you without more info -- you'd have to open it up and see if a ribbon cable was disconnected, or if the digitizer was damaged, or if it's separated from the glass, etc.

Comment: @MatthewRead I opened it and every thing is fine nothing seems broken. btw I didn't disassemble the PCB and anthena and etc, just opened the screws and ribbon cable and other parts were connected.